# What characters and skins can I unlock?

Tags: runner2

I know there's different skins and characters you can unlock in game for Bit Trip Runner 2.  My question is that what are the skins and characters I can unlock? What levels do I find them in (or what do I have to do to get them)?

Are there also other skins for other characters besides Commander Video? If so, what are they, and how do I unlock them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a total of 8 characters. 2 are unlocked immediately (CommanderVideo and CommandGirlVideo). Five of the other characters are unlocked one per world. The last one is unlocked by completing all 25 Retro Challenges.

---

Commander Video (9 skins) - Default

- Default: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arRPe.png) [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORorS.png)
- Beat.Trip: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izImI.png) [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5ivA.png)
- Gettin' Schlortzed: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2uM3.png)
- In the Buff: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLhoK.png) Unlocked in World **2**, *Galloping Gangplanks*
- Power Mitten: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfdG2.png) Unlocked in World **2**, *Crate Expectations*
- Inversion: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0lKA.png) Unlocked in World **3**, *Morning Wood*
- Mac Daddy: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x06sQ.png) Unlocked in World **3**, *UFO OMG*
- For Android: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQv6b.png) Unlocked in World **4**, *Devil's Marbles*
- F...ing Turkey Suit: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFd1s.png) Unlocked in World **5**, *Afterglow*

---

Commandgirl Video (8 skins) - Default

- Default: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW3nT.png)
- Purple Swan: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phYBK.png)
- Throw Back: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1anAV.png)
- Rebel Belle: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ll8.png)  Unlocked in World **2**, *Soggy Bottoms*
- Packed: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxWx0.png) Unlocked in World **2**, *Listing Isthmus*
- Jog Now: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Xj2.png) Unlocked in World **3**, *Bigfoot's Big Foot*
- Inversion: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFXfa.png)Unlocked in World **4**, *Pilce Bump*
- Riveting Laborer: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9PEl.png) Unlocked in World **5**, *Supraliminal Slide*

---

[Unkle Dill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tI7h.jpg) (6 skins) - Unlocked in World **1** (The Welkin Wonderland), *Every Cloud*

- Default: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O4HD.png)
- Gag on This: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTguM.png)
- Cucumber Bumpkin: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5EW6.png)
- Clever Pickle: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4OX4.png) Unlocked in World **2**, *Salty Sprint*
- Made Man: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpdZp.png) Unlocked in World **4**, *Bumpin' Ulcers*
- Tough Gerkin: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uboAB.png) Unlocked in World **5**, *Response-ability*

---

[Reverse Merman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYwwg.jpg) (6 skins) - Unlocked in World **2** (The Emerald Brine), *Salty Splendor*

- Default: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTPxz.png)
- Bowled Over: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODFMN.png)
- Playing Koi: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxS1W.png) - Unlocked in World **2**, *Fluid Freeway*
- Mecha Mahi: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwdIL.png) - Unlocked in World **3**, *Blabbage*
- Highly Trouted: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j60v.png) Unlocked in World **4**, *Grumbling Cravages*
- Re Fezzed: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycsXs.png) Unlocked in World **5**, *Extralogic*

---

[Whetfahrt Cheeseborger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLv53.jpg) (6 skins) - Unlocked in World **3** (The Supernature), *Slap Stick*

- Default: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQGl2.png)
- Pretty: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hLql.png)
- You Höser: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0aaK.png)  Unlocked in World **3**, *Lumber Jackson*
- Get Blue: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50WG5.png)  Unlocked in World **2**, *Aquatic Symphonic*
- Kung Fu Fighting: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f46Gx.png) Unlocked in World **4**, *Sweaty Dangle*
- Vegetarian: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJIKL.png) Unlocked in World **5**, *Hyperbrain*

---

[Pitazo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0lAI.jpg) (6 skins) - Unlocked in World **4** (The Mounting Sands), *Grumble Gallop*

- Default: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwgXI.png)
- Heart Transplant: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rteAt.png) Unlocked in World **2**, *Brine Time*
- Zap a Toes: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIfB6.png) Unlocked in World **3**, *Harsh Gribaldeen*
- All Brassed Up: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBci0.png) Unlocked in World **3**, *Treeathalon*
- Boarding Call: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PEnc.png)
- Can't Catch Me: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQGuN.png) Unlocked in World **5**, *Hypnogogic Logic*

---

[Captain Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfVB3.jpg) (6 skins) - Unlocked in World **5** (Bit.Trip), *Sweet Eyefuls*

- Default: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfV3W.png)
- Long Run: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXa5u.png)
- Super Saver: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlt41.png) Unlocked in World **4**, *Wrongledoo*
- Done Up: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUCx5.png) Unlocked in World 4, The Doleful Unders
- Manly Runner: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48qh0.png) Unlocked in World **5**, *Megathon*
- Hardcore: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy43r.png) Unlocked in World **5**, *Ultravision*

---

[Retro CommanderVideo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmXcH.jpg) (1 skin) - Unlocked by completing all 25 **Retro Challenges**

- Default:

---

Answer (score -1):

Hamburger man is on the level called "Slap Stick"

Comment: Hi Kurt, and welcome to Arqade! I think this answer alone is a bit weak, but that it would fit very well as an edit to the other Community Wiki answer. Would you mind suggesting it as an edit to that post instead?